# Ansible "required for this module" dependency issue (with Linode module)

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I've installed Ansible on Ubuntu and running:

```
 ansible testserver -m linode  -a 'state=stopped'
```

gives the error:

```
testserver | FAILED >> {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "linode-python required for this module"
}
```

I installed `linode-python` successfully with `pp install linode-python` and I can run `import linode` in Python. So how can I get this module working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I realised this should be a local action, because we're not actually trying to run a command on the remote server. Which means I have to run this against localhost. So first I had to ensure I could ssh into localhost:

```
cd ~/.ssh; cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

Then I changed the machine to localhost:

```
ansible localhost -m linode  -a 'state=stopped ...'
```

I'm still having some issues with that, but it seems to be running the module now.

[Blogged it.](http://softwareas.com/ansible-and-linode-what-i-learned-about-controlling-linodes-from-ansible)

Comment: You actually should not need to ssh in to your localhost. You can use a local connection to run modules directly on the host: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure : you have to install linode-python on the distant machine, not on the host.

Comment: I did come across that issue with `linode-mySqlDb required for this module` error, when I realised it wants mySQL to be installed on the remote machine. In this case, I realised it needs to be run as a local action. (See my answer.)